# How can I create a WordPress blog in a subdirectory on my GoDaddy Windows shared hosting account?

Tags: wordpress, blog, godaddy, shared-hosting

How can I create a WordPress blog in a subdirectory on my GoDaddy Windows shared hosting account for my domain name?

The URL should look like this: `www.example.com/blog/sme/abc-wxy-zdg` or this:
`www.example.com/blog/seo/qwer-58-ping`

I had already purchased my domain name and my website is also up.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a blog in a subdirectory as follows:

1. Go to your domain's root directory in your hosting account.
2. Create a new subdirectory named `/blog`
3. Install WordPress into the `/blog` subdirectory as detailed under GoDaddy's help document: [Installing WordPress on Your Hosting Account](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/834/installing-wordpress-on-your-hosting-account?countrysite=in) (see the Windows(Plesk) section if you're using Plesk).

So now you'll be able to manage your blog under a subdirectory, and it will have a URL like:

Blog URL: `www.example.com/blog`

Admin URL: `www.example.com/blog/wp-admin`

Comment: I am using cloudflare as my CDN and that doesn't allow me to install wordpress on my hosting plan. 
Any other way to do this ? Blogger will also work.

Comment: Blogger will not help to set up blog on custom domain.

Comment: @JackStern CloudFlare works fine with WordPress - see [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare/) and [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201717894-Using-CloudFlare-and-WordPress-Five-Easy-First-Steps).

Comment: I had added this on my godaddy windows shared hosting. 

This is the error that i got : http://postimg.org/image/mjzr28sol/
And I am sure that i'm using asp.net 4.0 as my whole website runs on that.

On asking godaddy support they said it's due to cloudflare nameservers but even after changing them also it doesn't seem to work. 
Any suggestions what should I do now ??

Comment: @JackStern It appears you're running into a troubleshooting issue, which is off-topic for this site. I'd suggest adding the default GoDaddy nameserver back (so that CloudFlare is no longer in the mix), and work with GoDaddy's hosting support team on the .Net configuration issue. Once you get that worked out, you can add CloudFlare back, but you might have to use their Page Rules and/or disable caching since you're running a dynamic site, which CloudFlare can have caching issues with.